# How to speed up the solution of a linear system?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm solving large linear systems of full matrix. I need the fastest option.
So far I wrote the below code:

```
    n = 2000;
    matrix = Table[RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
    vector = Table[RandomReal[-1, 1][[1]], {i, 1, n}];
    matrix = Table[If[i == j, matrix[[i, j]] *= -100, matrix[[i, j]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
    sollinearsolve = LinearSolve[matrix, vector] // AbsoluteTiming;
    Print["Time to solve using LinearSolve = ", sollinearsolve[[1]]]
    Inversevec = Inverse[matrix].vector // AbsoluteTiming;
    Print["Time to solve using Inverse = ", Inversevec[[1]]]
```

i found that `LinearSolve` is much faster than Inverse. is there a faster way to solve the linear systems above?

Comment: LinearSolve is not only faster but also more numerically stable. I also use the LeastSquares function with large matrices and have found the performance to be excellent (as fast as MATLAB).

Comment: Considering that your matrix is dense and unstructured, you can't do better than `LinearSolve[]`.